# Holographic dual of a star?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, string-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle

In AdS/CFT, we know that the AdS-Schwarzschild black hole is dual to a thermal state (or the thermofield double for the two-sided case). Suppose, instead of a black hole, we have a star in the bulk which also has the AdS-Schwarzschild outside it, what is the boundary CFT state dual to this geometry? Is it close to a thermal state?

Comment: See this published paper in JHEP: [Degenerate stars and gravitational collapse
in AdS/CFT](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/JHEP01(2011)144.pdf) Perhaps useful.

Comment: @SG8 Thanks for the reference. This is in line with what I want. In general, I find the question of "what is the CFT state dual to geometries other than black holes" is barely discussed in the literature.